# Laravel- calling PHP function from Angular to update database gives error: Expression expected

Tags: php, database, angular, laravel

I'm working on a Laravel application, and have just added a couple of fields to a form to allow users to add two new contacts to an account. The fields are displayed in a table in the form (file is accounts-table.html) with:

```
<!--Letter Addressee Name -->
<td *ngIf="!responseData.loading" class="width-1 visible-lg-table-cell">
    <input type="text" name="letterAddresseeNameTextField" ng-value= getLetterAddresseeName(responseData) ng-change = "getLetterAddresseeName()"><br>


</td>

<!--Preferred Addressee Name -->
<td *ngIf="!responseData.loading" class="width-1 visible-lg-table-cell">
  <input type="text" name="preferredAddresseeNameTextField" ng-value = getPreferredAddresseeName(responseData) ng-change = "getPreferredAddresseeName()" ><br>

</td>
```

In the TS for this form (account-table.ts), I have added the functions that are called by the `ng-change` attributes of the table cells:

```
public getLetterAddresseeName(data) {
    if(data.myAccount='0') {
        //data.letterAddresseeName = letterAddresseeNameTextField.value;
        if(data.letterAddresseeName) {
            AccountsController::addAddresseesToAccount();
            console.log("data.letterAddresseeName: ", data.letterAddresseeName);
            return data.letterAddresseeName;
        }
        else {
            console.log("No letter addressee name in database ");
            return;
        }
    }
    else {
        if(data.groupTag == null) {
            console.log("data.groupTag == null ");
            return;
        }
        else if(data.groupTag.indexOf('PENDING') > -1) {
            console.log("data.group.indexOf('PENDING') > -1 ");
            return;
        }
        else {
            console.log("Else statement of getLetterAddresseeName() reached ");
            return;
        }
    }
}

public getPreferredAddresseeName(data) {
    if(data.myAccount='0') {
        if(data.preferredAddresseeName) {
            AccountsController::addAddresseesToAccount();
            console.log("data.preferredAddresseeName: ", data.preferredAddresseeName);
            return data.preferredAddresseeName;
        }
        else {
            console.log("No preferred addressee name in database ");
            return;
        }
    }
    else {
        if(data.groupTag == null) {
            console.log("data.groupTag == null ");
            return;
        }
        else {
            console.log("Else statement of getPreferredAddresseName() reached ");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The `addAddresseesToAccount()` PHP function that's being called in these TS functions to actually add the new contacts to the account with:

```
AccountsController::addAddresseesToAccount();
```

is defined in AccountsController.php with:

```
public function addAddresseesToAccount( Request $request)
{
    $account = app\Account::find($request->input('accountId'));
    //dd("Value of account: ", $account);
    if($request->input('letterAddresseeNameTextField') != null)
    {
        $account->letterAddresseeName = $request->input('letterAddresseeNameTextField'.value);
        $account->save();
    }
    else
    {
        dd("letterAddresseeNameTextField value is blank ");
    }

    if($request->input('preferredAddresseeNameTextField') != null)
    {
        $account->preferredAddresseeName = $request->input('preferredAddresseeNameTextField'.value);
        $account->save();
    }
    else
    {
        dd("preferredAddresseeNameTextField value is blank ");
    }
    return $account;
}
```

When I run my application using the commands:

> gulp copy:angular
>
> ng build --watch --sourcemaps=false

the `ng build` command starts compiling the Angular, but then throws up an error that says:

> Error in path/accounts-table.ts(519, 36): error TS1109: Expression expected.
>
> path/accounts-table.ts(547, 36): error TS1109: Expression expected.

The two lines it's complaining about are the lines where I'm calling the PHP function to actually update the account with the new addresses that have been entered into the form.

Can anyone point out to me what I'm doing wrong here? Why am I getting these errors telling me that an expression is expected? I don't want an expression returned, just to update the account in the database...

Answer (score 0):

There's no way you can access php functions from TS directly. You'll need to associate the functions to routes in routes/web.php and send the data using AJAX.